# How can I match a whole word in JS?

Tags: javascript

I've searched a lot questions to find a way to a Regex that matches a whole word only. I came up with several answers and questions but a lot of them are not what I need.

For example one of the best rated question on SO shows up with this solution:

```js
let regx = new RegExp( "(^|\s)element-pattern(?=\s|$)" );

let text = "element-pattern";

if(text.match(regx)) {
  console.log("in it");
}

text = "element-pattern has-variations";

if(text.match(regx)) {
  console.log("in it");
} else {
  console.log("not in");
}
```

The problem I have is that it matches too good for me. In my example the second statement should also be true. What can I change on my RegEx so that it don't fails the second time?

Comment: Use a word boundry? `\b`

Comment: It's an escaping problem. Try `/(^|\s)element-pattern(?=\s|$)/` or `new RegExp("(^|\\s)element-pattern(?=\\s|$)")`. But as pointed out above, `\b` is a clearer fit for your use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are creating a RegExp object from a string. When you use backslash (\) in a regular JS string, it is interpreted as an escape character, so `\s` becomes just `s`. Use a RegExp literal instead. You could also just escape the backslashes like `new RegExp( "(^|\\s)element-pattern(?=\\s|$)" )`, but I prefer the literal notation.

```js
let regx = /(^|\s)element-pattern(?=\s|$)/

let text = "element-pattern";

if(text.match(regx)) {
  console.log("in it");
}

text = "element-pattern has-variations";

if(text.match(regx)) {
  console.log("in it");
} else {
  console.log("not in");
}
```